# How to get every day except weekend or Saturday or Sunday between two dates in java?

Tags: java, datetime, date

hi all how to generate dates if the start date and end date are provided in java?

like the following :

Ex : if the `start date is 15-04-2012` and `end date is 15-06-2012` having this i want dates to be like the following and the list should omit `saturday` and `sunday`

`1.15-04-2012,`
`2.16-04-2012,`
`3.17-04-2012,`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`.`
`15-06-2012`

I have done like the following but it will generate for one month if the date range is of same month.
`

```
public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> getWorkingDaysMap(int year, int month, int day){
        int totalworkingdays=0,noofdays=0;
        String nameofday = "";
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> workingDaysMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
        Map<String,String> holyDayMap = new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        noofdays = findNoOfDays(year,month,day);

        for (int i = 1; i <= noofdays; i++) {
            Date date = (new GregorianCalendar(year,month - 1, i)).getTime(); // year,month,day
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            nameofday = f.format(date);

            String daystr="";
            String monthstr="";

            if(i<10)daystr="0";
            if(month<10)monthstr="0";

            String formatedDate = daystr+i+"/"+monthstr+month+"/"+year;

            if(!(nameofday.equals("Saturday") || nameofday.equals("Sunday"))){
                workingDaysMap.put(formatedDate,formatedDate);
                totalworkingdays++;
            }
        }

        return workingDaysMap;
    }
```

So please do advice me how to go about.

Regards
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the following [joda-time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
import org.joda.time.DateTimeConstants;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public class DatesexcludingWeekend {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDate start = new LocalDate(2012, 06, 15);
        final LocalDate end = new LocalDate(2012, 07, 14);
        LocalDate weekday = start;
        if (start.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY|| start.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY) {
            weekday = weekday.plusWeeks(1).withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
        }

        while (weekday.isBefore(end)) {
            System.out.println(weekday);
            if (weekday.getDayOfWeek() == DateTimeConstants.FRIDAY)
                weekday = weekday.plusDays(3);
            else
                weekday = weekday.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int noOfDaysBetween = 5;
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(startDate);

for(int index = 0 ; index < noOfDaysBetween; index++){
    int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    if( dayOfWeek!=Calendar.SUNDAY && dayOfWeek!=Calendar.SATURDAY) {
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: what happen if number of days more than 31? if you see the question it the star date and end date do not fall in same month.

Comment: Just put this code to your main method and try running and observe behavior

Comment: Calendar.DATE and Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH are synonyms. Calendar.add takes care of correct result.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    //15-04-2012
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 15);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    Date start = calendar.getTime();

    //15-06-2012
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
    Date end = calendar.getTime();

    calendar.setTime(start);
    Date d = null;
    while((d = calendar.getTime()).before(end) || d.equals(end)) {
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (day != Calendar.SATURDAY && day != Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            System.out.println(d);
        }
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer usage of LocalDate.

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2018, 6, 1);
       LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2018, 8, 1);

       LocalDate d = start;
       while(d.compareTo(end) <= 0) {
         if (d.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SATURDAY && d.getDayOfWeek() != DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) {
            System.out.println(d);
         }
         d = d.plusDays(1);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Tip: You can neaten that a bit by using `EnumSet`. Define `Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY );` and test `weekend.contains( d.getDayOfWeek() )`. An `EnumSet` takes little memory and is extremely fast to execute (just a bit-map internally).