# Iterate between two date range using Joda

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

In my code I need to iterate between a range of dates using Joda, and I already tried this:

```
for(LocalDate currentdate = startDate; currenDate.isBefore(endDate); currenDate= currenDate.plusDays(1)){
    System.out.println(currentdate);
}
```

The above code is working, but the iteration stops when `currenDate` reaches the day before `endDate`. What I want to achieve is that the iteration stops when `currentDate` is exactly the same as `endDate`.

```
for(Date currentdate = startDate; currentdate <= endDate; currentdate++){
    System.out.println(currentdate );
}
```

I know the code above is impossible, but I do it to make clear what I'd want.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there's a simple way around to your original code you posted, see my implementation below, just modified your for loop implementation:

```
    //test data
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now(); //get current date
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.plusDays(5); //add 5 days to current date

    System.out.println("startDate : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("endDate : " + endDate);

    for(LocalDate currentdate = startDate; 
            currentdate.isBefore(endDate) || currentdate.isEqual(endDate); 
            currentdate= currentdate.plusDays(1)){
        System.out.println(currentdate);
    }
```

Below is the Output (with respect to my localDate):

startDate : 2015-03-26
endDate : 2015-03-31
2015-03-26
2015-03-27
2015-03-28
2015-03-29
2015-03-30
2015-03-31

Hope this helps! Cheers. :)

Comment: `! currentDate.isAfter( endDate )` is shorter than `currentdate.isBefore(endDate) || currentdate.isEqual(endDate)`. In other words, use “is NOT greater than” as a shorter version of “is less than or equal to”. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44320192/642706) for complete example. And I now I see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44316083/642706) has the same idea, but in `for` loop versus my `while` loop.

Answer (score 4):

If you want your loop to stop when the date your iterating is the same as todays date, you can use an equality check for that.

Have a look at [.equals()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) on LocalDate

Here is a quick example:

```
public class DateIterator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate lastMonth = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1);
        LocalDate lastWeek = LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(1);
        LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

        List<LocalDate> dates = Arrays.asList(lastMonth, lastWeek, yesterday, today, tomorrow);

        for (LocalDate date : dates) {
            if (date.isEqual(today)) {
                System.out.println("Date is equal to todays date! Break out, or do something else here");
            } else if (date.isBefore(today)) {
                System.out.println("The date " + date.toString() + " is in the past");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The date " + date.toString() + " is in the future");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
The date 2015-02-25 is in the past
The date 2015-03-18 is in the past
The date 2015-03-24 is in the past
Date is equal to todays date! Break out, or do something else here
The date 2015-03-26 is in the future
```

Obviously, if that equality check passes, you'll need to break out of the loop etc.

Heres another that uses a specific date and increments 1 day at a time, which I think is a bit more like what you want

```
public class DateIterator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LocalDate specificDate = LocalDate.now().minusWeeks(1);
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        boolean matchFound = false;
        while (!matchFound) {
            if (!specificDate.isEqual(today)) {
                System.out.println(specificDate.toString() + " is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...");
                specificDate = specificDate.plusDays(1);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Date matches today!");
                matchFound = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2015-03-18 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-19 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-20 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-21 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-22 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-23 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
2015-03-24 is in the past, incrementing day and checking again...
Date matches today!
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand if you were iterating over an array of dates, or had a fixed data and incrementing 1 day at a time, but I've given examples of both. HTH

Comment: thanks for your reply, your second example is working, thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

If you want the loop to be inclusive of the endDate you can use `!currentDate.isAfter( endDate )`. This is logically equivalent to `currentDate.isBefore(endDate) || currentDate.equals(endDate)`.

The following example will print 6/1/2017 through 6/10/2017.

```
LocalDate startDate = new LocalDate( 2017, 6, 1 );
LocalDate endDate = new LocalDate( 2017, 6, 10 );
for ( LocalDate currentDate = startDate; !currentDate.isAfter( endDate ); currentDate = currentDate.plusDays( 1 ) )
{
    System.out.println( currentDate );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using java.time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 2 ) ;
```

By the way, you might want to add a sanity-check to verify that the ending is not before the beginning.

## Not After

I believe the logic you are looking for, to include the ending date, is “not after“. The `LocalDate` class includes a [`isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDate-) method, to which you can add a logical “NOT” (`!`).

Also, a `while` loop seems more appropriate and self-explanatory in this situation than a `for` loop.

```
LocalDate ld = start ;
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>() ;
while ( ! ld.isAfter( stop ) ) {
    dates.add( ld ); // Collect this date.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Setup the next loop.
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/1M3qtb).

> dates: [2017-01-23, 2017-01-24, 2017-01-25, 2017-01-26, 2017-01-27, 2017-01-28, 2017-01-29, 2017-01-30, 2017-01-31, 2017-02-01, 2017-02-02]

## Half-Open

> the iteration stops when currentDate reaches the day before endDate

This is actually desirable. Known as Half-Open, the common approach in date-time handling is to consider the beginning as *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a lunch break starts at 12:00:00 (noon) and runs up to, but does not include, 13:00:00 (1 pm). The month of January starts on January 1 and runs up to, but does not include, February 1. A week starts on a Monday and runs up to, but does not include the following Monday. Most usefully, this approach avoids the problem of determining the last split second of a date-time where some systems use milliseconds (x.999), some (x.999999), same nanoseconds( x.999999999 ), and others use variations such as 5 decimal places (x.99999). Instead we go up to, but not include, the first moment of the next hour or day etc.

I find that using Half-Open approach consistently throughout my code makes the code easier to read, easier to comprehend, and much less likely to result in off-by-one bugs. I have been caught in countless financial mystery problems that turned out to be confusion or misunderstandings about a report covering date for with inclusive vs exclusive dates. So if possible, train your users to think the Half-Open way consistently. If not feasible, then adjust your code so your logic and loops are using Half-Open internally at least.

Here is code similar to above, but using `isBefore` rather than `NOT isAfter`, to use Half-Open approach. The ending is Feb. 3 instead of Feb. 2.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.FEBRUARY , 3 ) ;  // Third instead of the Second of February, to be half-open.

LocalDate ld = start ;
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>() ;
while ( ld.isBefore( stop ) ) {  // Using "isBefore" for Half-Open approach.
    dates.add( ld ); // Collect this date.
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;  // Setup the next loop.
}
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/mNw4ya).

> start: 2017-01-23 | stop: 2017-02-03
>
> dates: [2017-01-23, 2017-01-24, 2017-01-25, 2017-01-26, 2017-01-27, 2017-01-28, 2017-01-29, 2017-01-30, 2017-01-31, 2017-02-01, 2017-02-02]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with joda-type but you could iterate at the interval (second, minute, hour, day, month, year) with [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) API, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072914/fetching-next-valid-day) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048943/how-to-get-every-day-except-weekend-or-saturday-or-sunday-between-two-dates-in-j) are examples

Answer (score 0):

Evevntually went for this solution:

`Range.inclusive(3, 0).map(i => LocalDate.now.minusDays(i)).foreach()`